# Interaction between two lists

Tags: python, list

There are two lists:

A:`[[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 5]]`

B:`[(0, 5), (0, 9), (1, 7), (5, 0), (5, 9), (7, 1), (9, 0), (9, 5)]`

The nummbers `0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7` in A correspond to

`(0, 5), (0, 9), (1, 7), (5, 0), (5, 9), (7, 1), (9, 0), (9, 5)` in B

Is there a shortcut to obtain the following:

`[[(0, 5), (0, 9), (5, 0), (5, 9), (9, 0), (9, 5)], [(1, 7),(7, 1)]]`for A?

Comment: Shortcut compared to what? Have you tried anything so far or you don't know how to achieve the desired result and are looking for a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and list comprehension, like this

```
>>> indexes = [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 5]]
>>> data = [(0, 5), (0, 9), (1, 7), (5, 0), (5, 9), (7, 1), (9, 0), (9, 5)]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [list(itemgetter(*item)(data)) for item in indexes]
[[(0, 5), (0, 9), (5, 0), (5, 9), (9, 0), (9, 5)], [(1, 7), (7, 1)]]
```

Instead you can use nested list comprehension, like this

```
>>> [[data[index] for index in items] for items in indexes]
[[(0, 5), (0, 9), (5, 0), (5, 9), (9, 0), (9, 5)], [(1, 7), (7, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use list comprehension:

```
>>> A=[[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 5]]
>>> B=[(0, 5), (0, 9), (1, 7), (5, 0), (5, 9), (7, 1), (9, 0), (9, 5)]
>>> C=[[B[i] for i in l] for l in A]
>>> C
[[(0, 5), (0, 9), (5, 0), (5, 9), (9, 0), (9, 5)], [(1, 7), (7, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the shortcut is:

```
[[B[j] for j in i] for i in A]
```